# How to insert print receipt in this sales inventory system

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is the code for the sales inventory and I want to add the Receipt of the products purchased The receipt option should be in text file format.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
import sqlite3
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Inventory System")

width = 1024
height = 520
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.config(bg="#6666ff")

#========================================VARIABLES========================================
USERNAME = StringVar()
PASSWORD = StringVar()
PRODUCT_NAME = StringVar()
PRODUCT_PRICE = IntVar()
PRODUCT_QTY = IntVar()
SEARCH = StringVar()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do - and what means `file format` for you.

Comment: if you want to put data from text file then simply read it - `open()`, `read()` - and put text in widget `Label` or `Text`